# Circle image appearing as oval in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Working on creating circular avatar images in a `Node` Web App and when I set the image's `Boostrap` class to:

```
class="rounded-circle"
```

It appears as an oval, rather than a circle.  I've seen similar questions on here where answers have indicated the original images dimensions may play a factor in the shape of the circle.  The below vanilla `CSS` with a custom class had the same effect in creating an oval instead of a circle:

```
.player-circle {
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

What can I do (**from a CSS or Bootstrap standpoint**) to ensure the avatar actually displays as a perfect circle rather than a more ovular shape?  Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define it as square,then apply border-radius.Here's the solution:

```css
.rounded-circle{
border:1px solid;
border-radius:50%;
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rounded-circle"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed.  I appreciate the workaround!

Comment: Thank You.I'm always happy to help :)

Comment: but this solution does not work very well with images, since its getting stretched

Comment: Initially crop the image and set equal width and height, then apply border radius property.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta determine the size of image and put `object fit: cover` to avoid stretching image on square shape

```
.object-fit-cover {
width:50px;
height:50px;
object-fit:cover
}
<img class='rounded-circle object-fit-cover' />
```